# sqlalchemy Counting comments with one level of nesting that related to an article via comments_articles table

Tags: python, database, count, sqlalchemy, relationship

Now I use below method to get counts of comment related with articles.
But It's too risky when I have N comments in article.
How can I Counting comments with one level of nesting once in sqlalchemy?
P.S Comment is used not only Article model but also other Models(Project, Page, Something..)

```
class Article(db.model)
    ...
    ...ORM definitions...
    def comment_count(self):
        count = 0
        for comment in self.comments.filter(Comment.subs.any()).all():
            count += comment.subs.count()
        count += self.comments.count()
        return count
```

And Comment is related to article.
In the above code, self is an article having many comments.
These two model related via comments_articles table.
The ORM definitions for the tables are written below.

```
comments_articles = db.Table('comments_articles',
                       db.Column('article_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('article.id'), nullable=False),
                       db.Column('comment_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('comment.id'), nullable=False))

class Comment(db.Model):
    """Comment model"""
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    main_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('comment.id'))
    level = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default=0)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    main = db.relationship('Comment', remote_side=[id], uselist=False,
                       backref=db.backref('subs', lazy='dynamic', cascade="all, delete-orphan", single_parent=True,
                                          order_by='desc(Comment.created_at)'))


class Article(db.Model):
    """Article model"""
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', secondary=comments_articles, lazy='dynamic',
                           backref=db.backref('article', uselist=False), cascade="all, delete-orphan",
                           passive_deletes=True, single_parent=True, order_by='desc(Comment.created_at)')
```

Comment: `Comment` and `Article` have a many-to-many relation? Surely a comment belongs to only one article but an article can have many comments. It looks like you should change it to `one-to-many`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Yes, it actually is an one-to-many relation. But if Comment model doesn't used only in Article model but also in other models(Project, Page, Something...), should I make more comment models?

Comment: If I understand you right, you can use comment's id as a foreign key in those tables and create more one-to-many relationships (without need for any more classes)

Comment: Tnanks. If I understand you right, that can not be one-to-many relationship. Because when the Article has a foreign key of Comment, it will be one-to-one relation. If I add style_id as a foreign key in Comment, it will works well as an one-to-many relationship. But I should make new Comment model to use Comment in other model like Project.

Comment: Not quite. A foreign key means one-to-many (Unless that foreign key has a unique constraint or is also the primary key in which case it becomes one-to-one). I'd suggest you re-read [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html)

Comment: Yes. But I want one(Article,Project,Page,etc)-to-many(Comment) reationship. Not one(Comment)-to-many(Article). Then I used many-to-many relationship. Perhaps I consider changing model relationship to one-to-many [ArticleComment,ProjectComment,EtcComment...] if its performance is better.

Comment: Ah now I get your point. Comments can occur on may different things (Articles/Projects etc). In that case it would be better to have separate tables for them - ArticleComment, ProjectComment etc. (As you are doing originally) though I am not sure if it is a good design.

Comment: Thanks.:D 
Do you have any idea to solve getting counts?

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import func
session.query(func.count(Comment.subs)).filter(Comment.subs != None)
```

I'm making an assumption that if there is nothing in Comment.subs that it is `None`.

Comment: Thanks ACV. But Comment is related to an article via comments_articles table. How can I get counting comments with one level of nesting related to an article via comments_articles table. Cheers.

Comment: Could you add the ORM definitions for the tables your referring to? That might help me understand the relationship statement a little better.

Comment: Thanks again! I added the ORM definitions to this question.